# Does the integral yield primes when the set of all $k$ consists of primes or semiprimes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, definite-integrals, prime-numbers, semiprimes

Let $\pi(x)$ be the prime counting function and $P$ be the set of primes. Is $\Psi(k)\in P$ when the set of all $k$ consists of primes or semiprimes?

$$\Psi(k)=\int_0^k\pi(x)\pi(k-x)dx,$$

where $k\ge13.$

For example, for $k \le 540$, $\Psi(k)$ is prime for $15$ values, namely:

$k=\{13,57,119,167,171,173,175,341,395,397,427,431,473,515,519\}.$

Comment: $\Psi(n) = \sum_{m \le n}\pi(m) \pi(n-m)= \sum_{m \le n} \sum_{p \le m} \sum_{q \le n-m} 1$ $ =  \sum_{p \le n, q \le n}  \sum_{m \in [p,n-q]} 1 = \sum_{p \le n, q \le n} \max(0,n+1-p-q)$

Comment: I think you mean to ask: "Is it true that $\Psi(k) \in P \implies k$ is prime or semiprime ". The question you ask now is different. $k = 19$ is prime but $\Psi(k) = 214$ is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking if the following implication holds:
$$k \text{ is prime or semiprime} \implies \Psi(k) \text{ is prime}$$
**then the answer is no**: $k=19$ is prime but $\Psi(k) = 214$ is not.

---

If you are asking if the other implication holds:
$$\Psi(k) \text{ is prime}\implies k \text{ is prime or semiprime} $$
**then the answer is also no**: $k = 171$ gives $\Psi(k) = 63097$ which is prime, but $k$ is not prime or semiprime as $171 = 3^2 * 9$.

---

If you are asking if this implication holds:
$$\Psi(k) \text{ is prime}\implies k \text{ has at most 2 distinct prime factors} $$
**then the answer is also no**: $k = 585$ gives $\Psi(k) = 1530913$ which is prime, but $k$ is has 3 distinct prime factors $585 = 3^2 * 5 * 13$.

Comment: I'm asking if the set of all $k$ that makes $\Psi(k)$ prime, consists of primes and semiprimes

Comment: @Ultradark That is the second part of my answer, and the answer is no.